# Экранирование символов

Tags: c#

Есть ли в c# функция, которая экранирует специальные символы, чтобы строку можно было безопасно использовать в xml???
Плюсом будет возможность обратного парсинга.
Пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Bsmessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <nick>Alex</nick>
    <password>werq34f34gfrvq32g424</password>
    <recipient>Andrew</recipient>
    <message>rsgr</message>
</Bsmessage>
```

Comment: В XML и в запросах в БД (SQL) разное экранирование. Какое именно вам нужно?

Comment: Вы [никогда не должны](http://bobby-tables.com/) составлять SQL-запросы вручную.

Comment: Забудем про бд.

Comment: @SanychGoilo а как именно вы хотите использовать строку в XML? Все стандартные методы работы с XML сами экранируют значения. Можете привести пример кода, в котором что-то идет не так?

Comment: Пользователь пишет сообщение и он отправляется на сервер по udp и там парсится.

Comment: @SanychGoilo как именно вы составляете этот xml? вручную складываете строки? Или через, например, через классы XElement / XDocument?

Comment: Хотелось бы через  XElement / XDocument, но потом все равно придется перевести его в строку, последнюю в массив byte...

Comment: Не надо переводить его в строку, а потом в массив байт. `XDocument` можно сразу записывать в поток!

Comment: Передаются через сокеты byte

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Ну так поищите в документации, как передать содержимое потока в сокет. Не будьте беспомощным, вы ж программист.

Comment: @Vladd Я и нашел вариант. Не понимаю, чем он так Вам не нравится.

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Вы можете, например, сконструировать [`NetworkStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8fz0y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) из сокета, и просто скопировать `XDocument` туда одной командой. Не заморачиваясь с байтами.

Comment: Хорошо, я позже рассмотрю Ваше предложение, но пока оно не касается темы вопроса.